# What is the best way to save credentials file with Python?

Tags: python, encryption, credentials

I have Python code that I want to use a lot of credentials and some "metadata" about each one of them (e.g. db credentials then I wand also store with it the tables I want to replicate)

What is the best way to store all this info with high level encryption?

Comment: It seems that this is a personal password manager scheme wtitten in python and requiring an Amazon server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

1. I wrote a [yaml](http://www.yaml.org/start.html) file with all those credentials.
2. I [created](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/create-keys.html) KMS key
3. I [upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/UploadingObjectsintoAmazonS3.html) this file to S3
4. When I uploaded the yaml file I chose [Server Side encryption (AWS KMS, Step 7)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/UploadingObjectsintoAmazonS3.html)

Comment: Great question! I save it as environment variable in specific `screen` session at the machine I'm running this script on.

Comment: @zaph Another option is to provide the key by passing it to the script as an argument. which is also a great solution

Comment: So the key is not saved in any file on the system?